# Cannot load mod_dav_svn.so on Apache 2.0

Tags: apache, svn

I am using Subversion for Apache 2.0

I copied following two files from Subversion/bin to Apache/modules:

```
-mod_dav_svn.so
-mod_authz_svn.so
```

And I copied the following lines to the httpd.conf file:

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module modules/mod_authz_svn.so

# Configure Subversion repository
<Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SVNPath "C:\svn"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Subversion repository"
    AuthUserFile "c:\svn_conf\passwd"
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

When I try to run Apache, it gives me the following error:

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 141 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot l
oad modules/mod_dav_svn.so into server: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I have been searching hours for the solution to the problem, but I am unable to fix it. How can I fix that problem and make Apache running?

Comment: Subversion modules for Apache 2.0 are not compatible with Apache 2.2, and vice versa. AFAIK, Apache 2.0 hasn't been supported by Subversion for a few years now. Make sure all of your versions match.

Comment: A little more info needed here such as:
- What OS are you using?
- what version of svn?
- is there a specific need to use Apache 2.0 instead of the latest and greatest?

Answer (score 3):

Directly give the absolute path for `mod_dav_svn.so` and `mod_authz_svn.so` from Subversion, instead of copying these file from `subversion/bin` into `apache/bin`.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that you have to uncomment these two modules in your httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
```